# Devel - Theme Developer popup can not be seen on "Manage fields" tab

Tags: theming, forms

I'm using the very useful [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module for theming and element display investigating purposes.
When enabled, it displays a floating "***Themer info***" checkbox on the bottom left corner of the browser's content area, if you put a tick in this box, a popup window appears where you can get some theming data, [like the one you can see here](http://drupal.org/node/209561).

OK, I would like to investigate some of the theming data on the "Manage fields" tab of the content type edit forms belonging to CCK. But this is a page where no "Themer info" is getting displayed. Why, and how could I "force" it to be displayed?

**Some images to be clear:**

- *editing the "Page" content type, "Edit" tab (`/admin/content/node-type/page`), here you can see the floating "Themer info" in the left corner*
  [image: editing the "Page" content type, first tab ("Edit"), here you can see the floating "Themer info" in the left corner]
- *editing the "Page" content type, **"Manage fields" tab** (`/admin/content/node-type/page/fields`), there is **no floating "Themer info"** in the left corner!!*
  [image: editing the "Page" content type, "Manage fields" tab, there is no floating "Themer info" in the left corner!!]

Any ideas, hacks are appreciated. :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is most likely a javascript issue. You should include any javascript errors being thrown on the page in the details of your question.  Also, there seems to be an open issue related to your problem (http://drupal.org/node/675214). It would be very helpful to the community as a whole if you provided any additional information you can on that issue thread so that the module maintainer can reproduce the problem and add a permanent fix to the module release.